# Convergence and Eventual Constancy

Tags: real-analysis

Let ($M, d0$) be a set with the discrete metric. Consider a sequence $(x_n)n∈N.
$
Show that $(x_n)n∈N$ converges iff $(x_n)n∈N$ is eventually constant

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. You will receive helpful comments to questions like this if you show your own progress first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to an element $x \in M$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $d_0(x_n, x) < 1/2$ for all $n \ge k$. Show that this implies $x_n = x$ for all $n \ge k$.

Conversely, if $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is eventually constant, there exists an $x \in M$ and a positive integer $k$ such that $x_n = x$ for all $n \ge k$. Thus, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $d_0(x_n, x) = 0 < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge k$. Consequently, $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $x$.